# C# "as" keyword with objects of various types

Tags: c#

How to correctly rewrite this code to be *foolproof* versus various types of input parameter? Currently this code fails if, for instance, input parameter is a valid instance of `DateTime`. I've just figured that out - it was wrongly returning `false` for todays date.

```
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        string field = value as string;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(field))
            return false;

        return true;
    }
```

Would be nice to know if this is possible without having multiple if statements (for every possible value 
type and even for some reference types, like the string).

EDIT: oh, of course, the requirement is for the object to not be null or whitespace (therefore it has to be castable or parsable to string, I guess).

Comment: You cannot check every possible value type, as there are infinitely many value types.

Comment: Do you mean `foolproof`?

Comment: Casting to string and parsing as string are two different things: which are you interested in?

Comment: What method are you overridding, and why the weak typing in your signature?

Comment: DateTime isn't a valid string so `false` seems OK. Maybe write a foolproof spec/question first?

Comment: value as string returns null for DateTime object. I guess want parsing.

Comment: ouch obviously a different kind of crowd in C# tagspace than what I'm used from asp.net tag..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not using `value.ToString()`? [After null check]

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    if(value==null)
       return false;
    string field = value.Tostring();

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(field))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: As conditions are parsed left to right you could condense this to if(value == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()) { return false; }

Comment: some posses the knowledge to provide the answer even if the question is not of the highest standard.

Comment: I would recommend `.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` or  adding a `.Trim()`, as always with string validations.

Comment: Thanks to Erv and Guffa who were also correct but Aliostad did it first that's why the checkmark.

Answer (score 4):

Your use of `as` seems atypical and unnecessarily obscure.  Given that you goal is to return false if the object is null or empty, use this code instead:

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    if (value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

If you are using .NET 4 and want to check for whitespace also and not just empty strings, the new `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` would be worth looking at instead of `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`.

Comment: yeah it is obscure, it doesn't work and it isn't my code, I inherited it. That's why the rewrite for..

Comment: My point was not to chastise, but was explaining *why* I recommended a solution that didn't use `as`.

Answer (score 0):

Any object can be converted to string, as it has a ToString method. Check if the reference is null, then turn it into a string and check the length:

```
public override bool IsValid(object value) {
  return value != null && value.ToString().Length > 0;
}
```